# Cannot scale background div image

Tags: html, css, image, background, scaling

For whatever reason I cannot manually scale the background image of a div no matter what do. background-size and max-height,width have no effect whatsoever. The image is ignoring my style tags. Can somebody please explain why I cannot format the div's background image? I would like to scale the img/Stage-Background.png down from 1600x1076 down to 750x650

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="SDL.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>

<img src="img/SDL 4 Final Recompress.jpg" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; " />

<div style="background-image:url(img/Stage-Background.png); background-size:80px 60px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;">
<center>
<embed
src="http://blip.tv/play/AwGUv2w"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="669"
height="500" allowscriptaccess="always"
allowfullscreen="true" style="margin-top:100px; margin-bottom:200px;">
</embed>
</center>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based out of my knowledge we **cannot scale a background image**

If your image dimensions are greater than that of the div then

```
<div style="width:400px; height:400px;background:url(xyz.png);"></div>
```

with xyz.png dimensions greater than div's width and height.

You can use:

```
background-position:center;
```

Else try using normal img tag then use absolute positioning to place your elements on top of the image.

```
<div class="your_box_element" style="width:400px;height:400px;position:relative;">
    <img width="400px" height="400px" />
    <div class="your_text_on_top_of image" style="position:absolute;top:0px; left:0px;">
           Your text and other elements go here
    </div>
</div>
```

The method to load the image of greater dimensions and then scaling won't give you good performance hence better to have the image scaled appropriately to the div element incase you want to use it as a background. Seeing your example its better if you make changes to the background image to the required size.

See this for more details on background position [background-position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) to set correct fit

If you want to learn more about background image positions and how they are used commonly on web  try reading about [Image Sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are dealing with this image: img/Stage-Background.png

Instead of background-size, use height & width parameters in px.

Also, if you can tell us what is the original size of the image, and what size you wish to keep for your DIV.

Comment: this just applies a matte to it. I would like to scale the img/Stage-Background.png down from 1600x1076 down to 750x650